# Приведение типов в +!{}[0]

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получилась единица?

```
+!{}[0] // =1
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `{}[0]` -> _undefined_, `!undefined` -> _true_, `+true` -> 1

Comment: @Grundy, а я сразу не допёр

Comment: @Grundy, добавь ответ не комментарием, а ответом. Пожалуйста :)

Comment: {}[0] - что это за синтаксис? Выглядит как объект с указанием порядкового номера элемента...Это применимо к объектам?

Comment: Ключами объекта могут быть любые строки, а `{}[0]` — это то же самое, что `{}['0']`.

Comment: Имеется в виду доступ к свойствам объекта через квадратные скобки?

Comment: Не нравится объект - возьмите массив: `+![][[]]`

Comment: @Alex, _Имеется в виду доступ к свойствам объекта через квадратные скобки_ - и к свойствам массива и к свойствам объекта можно обращаться как через `.`, так и через `[]`. Главное отличие в том, что при использовании точки имя свойства должно быть валидным js идентификатором, а это накладывает некоторые ограничения, например числа, не являются идентификаторами, поэтому их нельзя использовать с точкой. С другой стороны следующие записи эквивалентны и переменная в них может быть как массивом, так и объектом: `a['toString']()`, `a.toString()`

Comment: Вошло, спасибо!! )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr; `{}[0]` → *undefined*, `!undefined` → true, `+true` → 1

---

### [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Первое, что используется в данном выражении: [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) - возможность доступа к свойствам объектов, с использованием квадратных скобок и строкового ключа.

`{}[0]` - попытка взять свойство с именем *0* в пустом объекте. Так как такое свойство отсутствует - будет получен закономерный результат *undefined*.

---

### [оператор логического отрицания](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)(**!**)

Далее, к результату (*undefined*) применяется [оператор логического отрицания](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)(**!**). Данный оператор вернет применяет к операнду абстрактный метод [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean), и инвертирует результат.

Как можно заметить из таблицы, для *undefined* результат `ToBoolean(undefined)` → *false*, после инвертирования получаем *true*.

---

### [унарный оператор *+*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)

Далее, к результату (*true*) применяется [унарный оператор *+*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), который просто переводит результат в число. Для этого используется абстрактная функция [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)

Как можно заметить из таблицы, для *true* результат `ToNumber(true)` → *1*.