# Почему ""[1] выдает undefined?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему в js `""[1]` выдает `undefined`? Почему возможен такой синтаксис? Что это все значит? Как это вообще возможно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Приведение типов в +!{}\[0\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633390/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-0)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [JavaScript access string chars as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4051385/2076787)

Comment: Ну где тут дубликат-то?! Не вижу в том вопросе ничего про строки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68076/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Здравствуйте 
В JS:

```
""
```

это строка, при обращении к индексу 1

```
""[1]
```

мы получаем

```
undefined
```

Т.к. этот индекс отсутствует. Если же он будет, то мы получим символ, которому он соответствует

```
"123"[1]  //выведет 2, т.к. индексация начинается с 0
```

Comment: строка **Не** является массивом

Comment: @grundy я и не утверждал, что это массив, я написал "по сути" имея ввиду принцип доступа по индексам, однако думаю Вы правы и мне стоит подредактировать ответ, да бы не вводить в заблуждения остальных.

Answer (score 12):

`""` - является пустой строкой. Доступ к символам [строки](https://learn.javascript.ru/string) осуществляется также, как в массиве , вы можете обратиться к любому из них по индексу.

```
"строка"[1] // на выходе получается "т"
```

В вашем случае вы выходите за пределы массива, элемент с индексом `1` не определен.

Comment: строка **Не** является массивом

Answer (score 1):

Если разложить по полочкам, то ваш код равносилен чему то подобному:

```
var var1; 
var1 = ""; 
var1[1] === undefined //true
```

И т.к. string также может быть массивом ( строку можно представить как массивоподобный объект, в котором символы имеют соответствующие числовые индексы) , то обращение по индексу 1, когда длинна массива равна 0, вызывает undefined (т.е. `"".length = 0` )

Comment: string var1 - как-то не по джаваскриптовски

Comment: string **Не** является массивом

Comment: @Grundy Согласен, оговорка. Но массовоподобый объект ведет себя практически идентично с обычным массивом (не вдаваясь в глубокие особенности). Поэтому строку можно приблизительно приравнять к массиву из элементов.

Answer (score 0):

При обращении к символам строки с использованием нотации квадратных скобок происходит обращение к *свойству* (*property*) с указанным именем (в данном случае именем является число и можно проверить его наличие с помощью метода `hasOwnProperty`). В случае же обращения к несуществующему свойству возвращается неопределённое значение - `undefined`. При использовании же метода `charAt` с указанием индекса, которого нет в строке, вернётся пустая строка.